# passportjs local strategy not getting called

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am using express and passport to build a rest api backend and it seems that my localStrategy is not getting called on request.

The entry point of my application looks like the following:

*app.js*

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var config = require('./config/config');

var morgan       = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true})); 

app.use(passport.initialize());

//connect to mongodb
mongoose.connect(config.db, options);

//load models (shorten forEach)
...
require(__dirname + '/models/' + file)(mongoose);

//load passport config
require('./config/passport')(mongoose, passport);

//load routes
require('./config/routes')(app, passport);

//start server
var server = app.listen(3000, ....
```

*routes.js*

```
...
app.post('/auth', function(req, res){
    console.log("reached auth endpoint");
    console.log(req.body);
    passport.authenticate('local', { session: false}, function(err, user, info){
      console.log("Test:"+user);
      if(err) {
        console.log("Error1");
        return next(err)}
      if(!user){
        console.log("Error2");
        return res.json(401, {error: 'Auth Error!'});
      }
      console.log("Error3");
      var token = jwt.encode({ username: user.email }, "hanswurst");
      res.json({token: token});
    }),
    function(req, res){
      console.log("passport user", req.user);
    };
  });
```

*passport.js*

```
...
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(email, password, done){
    console.log("TEST");
    User.findOne({'email': email}, function(err, user){
      if(err){
        console.log("Unknown error");
        return done(err);
      }
      if(!user){
        console.log("No User found");
        return done(null, false);
      }
      if(!user.validPassword(password)){
        console.log("Password was incorrect");
        return done(null, false);
      }
      console.log("User was found");
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

The only result i get on form request is

```
reached auth endpoint
{ email: 'test@mail.com', password: 'secret' }
POST /auth - - ms - -
```

For me the request body looks fine and it should enter my LocalStrategy. I am bit helpless as i am not getting any other console output from this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you have some basic javascript syntax errors in routes.js. This part right here (lots of code removed for clarity) is broken:

```
passport.authenticate(/*...*/), function(req, res) {/*..*/};
```

It might have been that you just added some `console.log` calls in the wrong place. To clear up the confusion, `passport.authenticate()` does not perform the authentication right away, what it does is return a middleware for you. You would use it like this for example :

```
var middleware = passport.authenticate(...);
app.post('/auth', middleware);
```

So to fix your problem, try invoking the middleware returned by authenticate right away, like this:

```
app.post('/auth', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("reached auth endpoint");
    console.log(req.body);
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        session: false
    }, function(err, user, info) {
            console.log("Test:" + user);
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error1");
                return next(err);
            }
            if (!user) {
                console.log("Error2");
                return res.json(401, {
                    error: 'Auth Error!'
                });
            }
            console.log("Error3");
            var token = jwt.encode({
                username: user.email
            }, "hanswurst");
            res.json({
                token: token
            });
        })(req, res, next);
});
```

Also, I have to tell you that `require` caches modules. To make `config/passport.js` aware of mongoose and passport, you *should not* feed them as parameters like this:

```
require('./config/passport')(mongoose, passport);
```

Simply require them again inside `config/passport.js` like so:

```
// (in config/passport.js)
// Both of these vars point to the same thing you require'd in app.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
```

Answer (score 4):

**[Edit]** I Found the problem. Because Express is no longer supporting subpackages like body-parser etc, you need to set those separately. All would be well had I done that in the first place, but I only activated:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
```

You also need to set

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

To get it to work properly. Stupid oversight but still, got me stumped for 3 days.

---

I Have the same problem, but nothing seems to work for me though.

I'll drop the code from the top down in execution order

jade template

```
.navbar-right(ng-controller="mvNavBarLoginCtrl")
  form.navbar-form
    .form-group
      input.form-control(placeholder='Email', ng-model='username')
    .form-group
      input.form-control(type='password', placeholder='password', ng-model='password')
    button.btn.btn-primary(ng-click="signIn(username,password)") Sign In
```

Next step Login controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('mvNavBarLoginCtrl',function($scope, $http){
  $scope.signIn = function (username, password){

    console.log('un = ' + username);   // Prints fine in the console
    console.log('pw = ' + password);   // Prints fine in the console

    $http.post('/login', {username: username, password: password}).then(function(response){
      if(response.data.success){
        console.log('Logged in!!');
      }
      else{
        console.log('Failed to log in!!');
      }

    });
  }
});
```

Next step Route handler

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
      console.log(req.username);   // Already empty
      console.log(req.password);   // Already empty
      console.log(req.body);       // Already empty

      // Because of the use of AngularJS we can not call passport directly, 
      // missing req and res will break the code 

      var auth = passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user){

          console.log(user);     // prints undefined

          if(err){return next(err);}

          if(!user){res.send({success:false});}

          req.logIn(user, function(err){

              if(err){return next(err);}

              res.send({success: true, user: user});
          });

      });
      // call the auth function to start authenticate
      auth(req, res, next);
  });
```

Next step passport authentication handler

```
var User = mongoose.model('User');

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
      username: 'username',
      password: 'password'
    },
    function(username, password, done){

      console.log("called");  // never printed

      // find user based in mongoose schema see 'var User' 
      User.findOne({userName:username}).exec(function (err,user){

        console.log(user)     // never printed
        if(err){return done(err);}

        if(user){
          return done(null, user);
        }
        else{
          return done(null, false);
        }
      });
    }
));


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
  if(user) {
    done(null, user._id);
  }
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
  user.findOne({_id:id}).exec(function(err, user){
    if(user) {
      done(null, user);
    }
    else{
      done(null, false);
    }
  });
});
```

There are no errors not in the console and not as node output. I am stumped and read about 5 or so other thread with similar issues, nothing worked.

If somebody could give me the golden tip, I would be eternally gratefull.

Comment: app.use(bodyParser.json()); worked. You saved me from getting crazy.